# The specified module could not be found in unkown line 0

Tags: php, xampp

I'm having a problem with sql server drivers for a php project, I follow the instructions given by the documentation on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql), I added the dll's on the ext directory, changed the php.ini file and added the extensions like:

```
 extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll
 extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll
```

I restarted the pc and the server.

Php environment path is set and working.

however every time I tried to execute the server I get this error:

```
 [Mon Nov 21 14:23:30 2016] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
 dynamic library 'C:\php_7\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll' - The specified module 
 could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

 [Mon Nov 21 14:23:30 2016] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
 dynamic library 'C:\php_7\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll' - The specified
 module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0
```

What I'm missing

Comment: error seems clear, what dont you understand?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte windows 10

Comment: have you checked `php.ini` for `extention_dir` property? It should refer to the directory which extensions reside. Also use `phpinfo()` and see where PHP looks for its configuration (`php.ini`) file. Commonly, it looks into the same directory where php executable is, then looks for it in system partition (`C:\`) in windows, or /etc in Linux, depending on flags it has compiled against.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it worke by using the non thread safe **nts**, instead of the thread safe **ts**

```
  extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll
  extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

So I downloaded the php_ibm_db2.dll 5.6 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x86 extension from https://pecl.php.net/package/ibm_db2/1.9.9/windows, added it to php.ini and was getting the exact same error. In my case all I had to do was to downlaod the thread safe version of the lib: 5.6 Thread Safe (TS) x86.